# Implementing variable based logging?

Tags: java

I have made a nice UI with three different logs (a general log and two class specific ones).

Every log can print different lines with different colors.

I was thinking of doing this so I can show info/errors/warnings.
Now, the thing is, that I'd like to have detailed debug only when I set a variable (something like `detailedDebug = true`).

I'd like something like this:

```
Simple              | Detailed
Error thrown in ... | Error thrown.. + dump of all variables related to the error
```

Now, with if statements I can achieve that easily, but, that seems overly complicated (complicating the code for debugging reasons too).

How could I implement this (while making it easy to use and most importantly clean)?

Should I make a method in every class that uses the logging features that automatically checks for a variable then does what asked?

Comment: Use static logging method, SLF4J etc ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the the log level as the variable to control the detail. When you want more detail, turn the level down to FINEST.

Hoewever, some operations that you wish to log might require considerable resources to calculate the detail (example, you may retrieve info from the DB, etc). In this case you should use if statements because the resources will be consumed even if the log level is at ERROR level.

Example :

The following code will always execute :

```
logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Some detailed log info which sows the results from DB {0}",
    new Object[]{ getResults() });
```

If you only want to execute this code when you are showing FINEST, you need to wrap the statement in an if statement :

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
    // Some intensive logging
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I need to call the log method twice (in my case), once with the 'simple' version w/ Level.FINE, and once with the complex one w/ Level.FINEST?

Comment: If you do that it will be logged once when level == FINE and twice when level == FINEST. You need to resort to if statements if you only want it logged once.

Comment: Hmmm, will work on it. When POC is working I will select your answer. Thanks dude!

Comment: In java 8, the log methods accept suppliers, which removes the need for some of the conditionalization. E.g., just do `log.fine(() -> "value is: + " expensiveComputation());`.

Comment: It is very rare that one needs to use `isLoggable`.  Parameterized logging exists precisely to remove the need for that.  The correct approach is to call `getResults()` exactly once (not a second time for logging purposes), then pass the variable to `logger.log`, so its toString method will be only be called if FINEST is enabled.  Or, use a Supplier based method as Joshua suggested.